# facebook Malformed access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, malformed

After reading all tuts and questions on stackoverflow I still dont get it working
code:

```
<?php
include_once 'debug/debug.php';
if (isset($_GET["username"])) {

    $appId="XXX";
    $appSecret="YYY";

    $code = $_GET["code"];
    echo "Code: <br>" . $code . "<hr>";
    //Optain App Token!    
    $ch = curl_init ();

    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $appId .
        "&client_secret=". $appSecret. 
        "&grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    $access_token = explode("=", $result)[1];
    echo $access_token;

    //Option further Information
    $ch = curl_init ();

    //curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $code);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=" . $code . "&access_token=" . $access_token);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

The answer is:
{"data":{"error":{"message":"Malformed access token AQB6hhoeZJ1SR5RqtPp-iEDEd1Fg38GV95tW2YrVR9EfK6Y8H7QgcrSr8uagegIpKa4rPI7z4qSw45COZZL1XMDUuigsrBLNg5NKXl2bd9GPYC1Qo5peH81mGqP6LqK-orL3uqCH3Bta3kHOGp76RmK8p391soS47ZR8WE5gNx6s35qctgoHuWE47R0w93GeNglRxu2IUtVsGhZgyGiA9l12BMq9NX5O9Kcp2DupVqWs67Vnqz8MntrTx-AzbFhdHrYtWOhmFb8WybrT3ZuGqETZEAGc9JOTuhiHJW3Elp_rE7IWA50MIWsAaqM77fuI1Go","code":190},"is_valid":false}}

$code is given by login from facebook calling this uri: 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.mineforce.de/ms/fblogin.php?username=USERNAME 
I dont get it why the access-token should be wrong as we get it by facebook itself. 
the outprints etc can be found here: 
[http://www.mineforce.de/ms/fblogin.php?username=phibedy&code=AQB6hhoeZJ1SR5RqtPp-iEDEd1Fg38GV95tW2YrVR9EfK6Y8H7QgcrSr8uagegIpKa4rPI7z4qSw45COZZL1XMDUuigsrBLNg5NKXl2bd9GPYC1Qo5peH81mGqP6LqK-orL3uqCH3Bta3kHOGp76RmK8p391soS47ZR8WE5gNx6s35qctgoHuWE47R0w93GeNglRxu2IUtVsGhZgyGiA9l12BMq9NX5O9Kcp2DupVqWs67Vnqz8MntrTx-AzbFhdHrYtWOhmFb8WybrT3ZuGqETZEAGc9JOTuhiHJW3Elp_rE7IWA50MIWsAaqM77fuI1Go#*=*](http://www.mineforce.de/ms/fblogin.php?username=phibedy&code=AQB6hhoeZJ1SR5RqtPp-iEDEd1Fg38GV95tW2YrVR9EfK6Y8H7QgcrSr8uagegIpKa4rPI7z4qSw45COZZL1XMDUuigsrBLNg5NKXl2bd9GPYC1Qo5peH81mGqP6LqK-orL3uqCH3Bta3kHOGp76RmK8p391soS47ZR8WE5gNx6s35qctgoHuWE47R0w93GeNglRxu2IUtVsGhZgyGiA9l12BMq9NX5O9Kcp2DupVqWs67Vnqz8MntrTx-AzbFhdHrYtWOhmFb8WybrT3ZuGqETZEAGc9JOTuhiHJW3Elp_rE7IWA50MIWsAaqM77fuI1Go#_=_)


Secondly I dont get why fb puts #*=* at the end of the token

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The code works, I called some debug-code in java, so the code that I thought was called wasnt called :) 
It took me 4 hours to find it but whatever. If you follow the facebook-tut step by step everything should work fine.
Cheers :)